# How to use "stopAuto" function in bxslider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I have a bx slider which has 6 images. I want to go through each of them once then stop for a second and then begin again, then stop for one second again etc. It's mentioned here (http://bxslider.com/options) but with no full example.

This is the code I have now. It doesn't stop navigation images.

```
<script>
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    autoControls: true,
    speed: 1,
    pause:200
});
</script>
```

Sorry for the lame question. I am a still a newbie to jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set autoDelay option and onSlideAfter function

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3h0ewwz4/

```
var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    autoDelay:2000,
    onSlideAfter: function (slide, oldIndex, newIndex) { // add this function to solve issue
      if (newIndex === 5) { // remember, it's zero based indices with bxslider...5 is index of last image
        slider.stopAuto();
        setTimeout(function () {
            slider.goToSlide(0);
            slider.startAuto();
        }, 2000);
      }
    },
    autoControls: true,
    speed: 1,
    pause:200
});
```

Comment: also added one demo..check that